# Rails populate with default entries after database table was created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am having a checklist table with following columns:-

```
id  |  product_id  | content  |  archived
```

Once the user signs up product table is created and corresponding checklist table is also created.

I want to add default 5 entries with data for checklist table for each user after he/she signs up. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use after create callback:

```
User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :check_lists

  after_create :add_default_checklist

  def add_default_checklist
    default_check_lists.each do |check_list_data| # Define way to get default values
      check_lists.create(check_list_data)
    end
  end
end
```

You'll need to add `user_id` column to checklist

Comment: Great!! i can store **default_check_lists** in array right?. where can is have my **default_check_lists** method? Inside the same model or somewhere else?

Comment: Inside model and it should be an array of hashes. Alternatively you can read from yaml file

Comment: Hey thanks. I am having 25 default checklists. The code looks ugly if i put it in the same model. Can i have the YAML file externally and call it here in the model? Haven't done that before. How can i do that?

Comment: You may want to use a mass insert instead of 5 different queries though.

Comment: def default_check_lists 
  default_check_lists ||= YAML.load_file('check_lists.yaml')
end

Comment: It worked. I have used the YAML file to successfully load the default data. Thanks @andriy-baran

Comment: @max Thanks but I think instead of having mass entry as its only 25 checklist data YAML file is good to go.

Answer (score 2):

I would solve this with a [service object](https://www.engineyard.com/blog/keeping-your-rails-controllers-dry-with-services).

```
# app/services/default_checklist_service.rb
class DefaultChecklistService
  attr_accessor :user, :defaults

  def initialize(user, defaults = nil)
    @user = user
    @defaults = defaults || self.class.load_defaults
  end

  def self.call(user, defaults = nil)
     new(user, defaults).call
  end

  def call
    self.defaults.map do |attributes|
      user.checklists.create(attributes)
    end
  end

  private
  def self.load_defaults
    YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join('config', 'default_checklist.yml'))
        .try(:[], 'checklists')
  end
end
```

This creates a single purpose object which is easily tested. VS model callbacks which add more responsibilities to an already god like model and which are tricky to test and control when and where they fire.

```
# config/default_checklists.yml
checklists:
  -
    foo: 1
    bar: 2
  -
    foo: 2
    bar: 3
```

Note that this will create *n* (where *n* is the number of default items) separate insert queries which is not very fast. If the performance becomes an issue than you can use a mass insert instead:

```
# app/services/default_checklist_service.rb
class DefaultChecklistService
  # ...
  def call
    sql = "INSERT INTO users(user_id, foo, bar) VALUES "
    values = defaults.map do |a|
      "(#{@user.id}, #{a["foo"]}, #{a["bar"]})"
    end
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute( sql + values.join(', ') )
  end
end
```

Since creating the defaults is expensive and will slow your tests down I would not use a model callback. Instead call the service from the controller where you actually want the seeding to happen:

```
class UsersController
  def create
    @user = User.create(user_params)
    if @user.save
      DefaultChecklistService.call(@user)
      # ...
    else
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Note that you may have to call `spring stop` to get the Rails autoloader to pickup on the new "app/services" folder.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Definitely i will give it a try.